# how to get the response of Iframe submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, iframe, response

I have a form that has been called using a iframe, now when that form is submitted i want to catch a response in the main site from where the iframe was called and depending on it would enable/disable a button in main page.
Please anyone help me out..

Comment: `<iframe src="http://www.example.com/index.php"></iframe>` Now in this iframe location there is a form, on successful submission of this form, i need to set an event in the page form where it is called.

Comment: May be these will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508442/jquery-finding-an-element-within-iframe-by-its-text-and-adding-click-function
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe

Comment: Sorry guys i forgot to mention, both are in different domain.

Answer (score 8):

You could use window.postMessage API. 
Its is a HTML5 feature and not all browsers support this feature

In the Iframe and Parent Site you need a check if the browser does support postMessage

```
if (typeof window.postMessage != 'undefined') { }
```

you can send your message with

```
window.parent.postMessage("test","*");
```

In your Parent (Main Site) you need an eventlistener

```
window.addEventListener('message', receive, false);

function receive(evt)
{
  // handles the event
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `parent` from within the iframe once the form is submitted.

```
parent.document.getElementById('xx').innerHTML = "hello world";
```

Comment: the iframe location form and from where i am calling are in different domain... can you make me understand a bit more..